# Reading through a paper on got confused on this part

Tags: statistics

Look at the following  please :)

> Assuming an uninformative prior for $N$ then
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \log p(N \mid y) &=\text { const }+\log \mathrm{p}(\mathbf{y} \mid N) \\
> & \approx \text { const }-\frac{1}{2} \mathrm{BIC},\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (17)
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> using (16) and substituting for the BIC. Generally, the BIC would give an overprecise approximation
> to the posterior $p(N \mid y)$.

I'm kind of lost on how they got to (17) and the Bayesian information criterion.
(16) if it may be related

> $$
> \log \mathrm{p}(\mathbf{y} \mid N) \approx \log p(\mathbf{y} \mid \hat{\Theta}, N)-\frac{p_{N}}{2} \log (T),\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (16)
> $$